# MariaDB auto number on virtual machine

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a database running in MariaDB.  I use auto numbering for the primary key's, on my local development system everything works as expected.

The same database and system is installed on a clients system, in this case the client has chosen to run the installation on a virtual machine running Windows Server.

This system has been working find for several weeks, over the last few days some strange problems have occurred, today I tried to edit an existing record and instead of the record being updated a new record with a primary key of 0 was added to the database, so the auto increment isn't working reliably.

How can this happen?  What can cause it?

I will check and repair the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, the same database on two different systems, same version of mariadb, but a slightly different version of Windows.  A stored procedure on one system was send 0 instead of null.  On one system the 0 was treated as null and a new record was created, on the other system the 0 was interpreted as a database id and this caused the problem.

I now ensure that null is send if the ID is not > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Auto increment only kicks in when you insert and no value (for that attribute) is supplied. So you can still manually update it. I would say auto increment has not failed.

Comment: It has failed in that the record has a primary key of 0...how can that be a success?

Comment: It is probably "user error".  Let's see the statement that did the insert.  I suspect it has "0" being explicitly stored into the auto-inc column.